# Ukrainian citizen, living with Blue Card in Germany - can work remotely in Austria?

Tags: visa, working-visas, blue-card, paperwork

Right now we want to employ a programmer / IT specialist who has Ukrainian nationality and citizenship but is living in Germany (and has a Blue Card from Germany since 6 months ago).

Is he allowed to take full-time employment **remotely** in Austria (without moving to Austria, beside visiting for 1-2 weeks' intoduction time)?

Does he have to apply for a new Blue Card in Austria, even if he doesn't move to Austria?

Comment: I don't know the answer but it seems to me that your main problem is retaining a right to reside in Germany (if that's what you want to do). Once you have left your job, you are not entitled to a German blue card anymore. A job in Austria probably won't make you eligible for a German residence permit. An Austrian Blue card would *not* help as it wouldn't entitle you to reside in Germany (but only in Austria). There are other residence permits than the Blue card but they are typically not designed with remote work in mind either (although some are beginning to appear elsewhere in the world).